# Not able to export data with an excel sheet with my approach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, xlsx

When I am rendering the  with condition, I am able to export theDataSet data but for the searchOrderBy condition I am getting the below error.

ExcelFile.js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

only the theDataSet data is working for excel export.

Thank you for the help!!

Sorry for the large code.

```
 const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
 const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;

 
 let theData = [];
  
 allOrdersData.then(function(result){
  
  result && result.map(res=>{

    res.orderItems.map(val=>{
      
      // if(res.indexOf(res.))/deliveryDate , MOMENT(values.deliveryDate).tz(timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm A')
      theData.push([
        {value: !res.id || res.id == null ? '': res.id.toString(), style: {font:{color:{rgb:'008000'}, sz:"13"}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, fill: {patternType: 'solid', fgColor:{rgb:  res.id === res.deliveryInfo.id ?  'f7fd04': 'ffff00'} }},
        {value: !res.placedDate || res.placedDate == null ? '':MOMENT(res.placedDate).tz(timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm A'), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, fill: {patternType: 'solid', fgColor:{rgb:  res.id === res.deliveryInfo.id ?  'f7fd04': 'ffff00'} } },
        {value: !res.deliveryInfo || res.deliveryInfo == null ? '': MOMENT(val.deliveryDate).tz(timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm A'), style: {font:{sz:"13"}} , alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.deliveryInfo || res.deliveryInfo == null ? '': MOMENT(res.deliveryInfo.slotStart).tz(timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm A')+" - "+MOMENT(val.slotEnd).tz(timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm A'), style: {font:{sz:"13"}} , alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.status || res.status == null ? '': res.status.toString(), style: {font:{color:{rgb:'008000'}, sz:"13"}} , alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.customer.firstName || res.customer.firstName == null ? '': res.customer.firstName.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.deliveryInfo.addressLine1 || res.deliveryInfo.addressLine1 == null ? '': "Address Line 1: "+res.deliveryInfo.addressLine1.allReplace({'&@>': ',', '&@<>': ','}).toString()+", Address Line 2: "+res.deliveryInfo.addressLine2.allReplace({'&@>': ',', '&@<>': ','}).toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.deliveryInfo.postalCode || res.deliveryInfo.postalCode == null ? 'Not Specified': res.deliveryInfo.postalCode.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.customer.email || res.customer.email == null ? 'Not Specified':  res.customer.email.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.customer.phone || res.customer.phone == null ? 'Not Specified': res.customer.phone.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: res.deliveryInfo.zp === false ? 'false': 'true', style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !val.quantity || val.quantity == null ? '' : val.quantity.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !val.unitName || val.unitName == null? '': val.unitName.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !val.name || val.name == null ? '': val.name.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !val.status || val.status == null ? '':val.status.toString(), style: {font:{color:{ rgb: val.status === 'PAY_FAILED' ? 'FF0000' : '008000'}, sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.promo || res.promo == null ? 'None Is Applied': res.promo.code.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
    
        {value: val.unitPrice && val.unitPrice.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: val.totalPrice && val.totalPrice.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: res.pm && res.pm.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
    
        {value: !res.deliveryInfo.deliveryNote || res.deliveryInfo.deliveryNote == null? 'Not Specified':res.deliveryInfo.deliveryNote.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: res.deliveryInfo.go === false ? 'false': 'true', style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.deliveryInfo.gift || res.deliveryInfo.gift == null? 'Not Specified': res.deliveryInfo.gift.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
    
          ])
    })
        }//inner map
    
    );

});


//////////////////////////order data searched with mobile number or email to be exported


// for excel export
const getAllPagesMobileOrEmailOrders = async (custID, totalMobileOrEmailorders) => {
  // for excel export
  let allOrders = [];
  let pageNum = 0;
  while (pageNum < Math.ceil(totalMobileOrEmailorders / 20)) {
    let excelOrderAPI = "/orders/details?customerId.equals="+custID+"&customerId.specified=true&page="+pageNum+"&size=20";
        

    const order = await axios.get(excelOrderAPI, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: jwtToken,
        Accept: "*/*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "App-Token": "A14BC",
      },
    });

    if (order.data != null && order.data.length > 0) {
      order.data.map((res) => {
        allOrders.push(res);
      });
    }
    pageNum++;
    
  }//end of while

return allOrders;

};


//whenever the searched icon is called prepare the dataset



 const prepareSearchedDataForExport = (mobileOrEmailOrderTobeExportedExcel) =>{
  let searchedExcelDataSet = [];

    mobileOrEmailOrderTobeExportedExcel && mobileOrEmailOrderTobeExportedExcel.map(res=>{

    res.orderItems.map(val=>{
      
      // if(res.indexOf(res.))/deliveryDate , MOMENT(values.deliveryDate).tz(timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm A')
      searchedExcelDataSet.push([
        {value: !res.id || res.id == null ? '': res.id.toString(), style: {font:{color:{rgb:'008000'}, sz:"13"}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, fill: {patternType: 'solid', fgColor:{rgb:  res.id === res.deliveryInfo.id ?  'f7fd04': 'ffff00'} }},
        {value: !res.placedDate || res.placedDate == null ? '':MOMENT(res.placedDate).tz(timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm A'), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, fill: {patternType: 'solid', fgColor:{rgb:  res.id === res.deliveryInfo.id ?  'f7fd04': 'ffff00'} } },
        {value: !res.deliveryInfo || res.deliveryInfo == null ? '': MOMENT(val.deliveryDate).tz(timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm A'), style: {font:{sz:"13"}} , alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.deliveryInfo || res.deliveryInfo == null ? '': MOMENT(res.deliveryInfo.slotStart).tz(timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm A')+" - "+MOMENT(val.slotEnd).tz(timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm A'), style: {font:{sz:"13"}} , alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.status || res.status == null ? '': res.status.toString(), style: {font:{color:{rgb:'008000'}, sz:"13"}} , alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.customer.firstName || res.customer.firstName == null ? '': res.customer.firstName.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.deliveryInfo.addressLine1 || res.deliveryInfo.addressLine1 == null ? '': "Address Line 1: "+res.deliveryInfo.addressLine1.allReplace({'&@>': ',', '&@<>': ','}).toString()+", Address Line 2: "+res.deliveryInfo.addressLine2.allReplace({'&@>': ',', '&@<>': ','}).toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.deliveryInfo.postalCode || res.deliveryInfo.postalCode == null ? 'Not Specified': res.deliveryInfo.postalCode.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.customer.email || res.customer.email == null ? 'Not Specified':  res.customer.email.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.customer.phone || res.customer.phone == null ? 'Not Specified': res.customer.phone.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: res.deliveryInfo.zp === false ? 'false': 'true', style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !val.quantity || val.quantity == null ? '' : val.quantity.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !val.unitName || val.unitName == null? '': val.unitName.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !val.name || val.name == null ? '': val.name.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !val.status || val.status == null ? '':val.status.toString(), style: {font:{color:{ rgb: val.status === 'PAY_FAILED' ? 'FF0000' : '008000'}, sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.promo || res.promo == null ? 'None Is Applied': res.promo.code.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
    
        {value: val.unitPrice && val.unitPrice.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: val.totalPrice && val.totalPrice.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: res.pm && res.pm.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
    
        {value: !res.deliveryInfo.deliveryNote || res.deliveryInfo.deliveryNote == null? 'Not Specified':res.deliveryInfo.deliveryNote.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: res.deliveryInfo.go === false ? 'false': 'true', style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
        {value: !res.deliveryInfo.gift || res.deliveryInfo.gift == null? 'Not Specified': res.deliveryInfo.gift.toString(), style: {font:{sz:"13"}}, alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}},
    
          ])
    })
        }//inner map
    
    );

   const theDataSet1 = [
      {
        columns:[        
          {title: "Order ID", style: {font: {sz:'14', color:'ffffff',bold: true}}, alignment:{vertical: 'center'},width:{wpx: 80} },
          {title: "Placed Date", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}}, alignment:{vertical: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 160} },
          {title: "Delivery Date", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}}, alignment:{vertical: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 160} },
          {title: "Delivery Slot", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{vertical: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 320} },
          {title: "Status", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 90} },
          {title: "Customer Name", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 125} },
          {title: "Address", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 380} },
          {title: "Postal Code", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 100} },
          {title: "Email", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 180} },
          {title: "Phone", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 125} },
    
          {title: "Zero Plastic", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 100} },
          {title: "Number of items", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 125} },
          {title: "Packing Size", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 100} },
          {title: "Order(item description)", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 165} },
          {title: "Item Status", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 100} },
          {title: "Promo Code", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 100} },
    
          {title: "Unit Price", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 80} },
          {title: "Total Price", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 80} },
    
          {title: "Payment Method", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 125} },
          {title: "Delivery Note", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 125} },
          {title: "Gift(Y/N)", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 80} },
          {title: "Gift Message", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 125} },
    
        ],
        data:   searchedExcelDataSet
      }
    ]
  
    getDataSet(theDataSet1);


}//end of func

const getDataSet = (dataSe)=>{

  return dataSe;

}
let dataSet1 = [];
useEffect(() => {

  dataSet1 = getDataSet();

}, [getDataSet, dataSet1])

const theDataSet=[
    {
      columns:[        
        {title: "Order ID", style: {font: {sz:'14', color:'ffffff',bold: true}}, alignment:{vertical: 'center'},width:{wpx: 80} },
        {title: "Placed Date", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}}, alignment:{vertical: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 160} },
        {title: "Delivery Date", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}}, alignment:{vertical: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 160} },
        {title: "Delivery Slot", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{vertical: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 320} },
        {title: "Status", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 90} },
        {title: "Customer Name", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 125} },
        {title: "Address", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 380} },
        {title: "Postal Code", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 100} },
        {title: "Email", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 180} },
        {title: "Phone", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 125} },
  
        {title: "Zero Plastic", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 100} },
        {title: "Number of items", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 125} },
        {title: "Packing Size", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 100} },
        {title: "Order(item description)", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 165} },
        {title: "Item Status", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 100} },
        {title: "Promo Code", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 100} },
  
        {title: "Unit Price", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 80} },
        {title: "Total Price", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 80} },
  
        {title: "Payment Method", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 125} },
        {title: "Delivery Note", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 125} },
        {title: "Gift(Y/N)", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 80} },
        {title: "Gift Message", style: {font: {sz:'14', bold: true}},alignment:{horizontal: 'center'}, width:{wpx: 125} },
  
      ],
      data: theData
    }
  ]




//jsx

return(<div  style={theData ? {display:'flex',alignItems:'right',float:'right'} : {display:'flex', cursor:'not-allowed', opacity:0.5,alignItems:'right', float:'right'} }>
                                      <div style={theData  ? {display:'flex',alignItems:'right', pointerEvents:'auto',float:'right'} : {display:'flex', pointerEvents:'none', opacity:0.5,alignItems:'right', float:'right'} }>
                                        <Tooltip
                                          title="export"
                                          placement="top"
                                          arrow
                                          PopperProps={{
                                              popperOptions: {
                                                  modifiers: {
                                                  offset: {
                                                      enabled: true,
                                                      offset: '1px, 0px',
                                                      },
                                                  },
                                                  },
                                              }}
                                            >
                                            
                                            <ExcelFile
                                              filename="orders"
                                              element={<Button style={{}}>
                                                          <img src={ExcelImage} style={{height:'35px',width:'35px'}} alt="excel_import_image"/>
                                                      </Button>
                                                      }
                                              >
                                                {
                                                 (searchOrderBy =='mobile' || searchOrderBy =='email') && (searchedORDERID.length >= 1) ? <ExcelSheet dataSet={dataSet1 && dataSet1} name="orders_data" /> : <ExcelSheet dataSet={theDataSet} name="orders_data" />
                                                }
                                                                                                                
                                              </ExcelFile>
                                          </Tooltip>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
)
```

Comment: As the error said, you are trying to use forEach in a variable that is undefined. I can't find any forEach in this code. Errors usually show the stack where it was generated, you should look for the file and line number to easily find the problem. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get indicates that somewhere you call forEach on a variable that is undefined.

Steps to debug:

- find the call to forEach (I wasn't able to find it in the code you provided)
- check why the variable is undefined or not an array

Comment: Hi @phn, Thank you for trying to help. react-data-export is a library that takes data via the dataSet attribute it provides. So the forEach loop is being run in the library that i have installed. So, I don't think it's an issue with that but maybe the data that I am passing is undefined. I can see my data in the log but it is not being used by the library that I am using. Don't know why though, still trying.

Comment: My final shot then, since I'm not that adapt at react. I notice the following `dataSet={dataSet1 && dataSet1}` which seems odd to pass as a prop. Since `dataSet={theDataSet}` works, I would suggest to try `dataSet={dataSet1}` instead.

Comment: That **&&** operator is used here just to verify that the data is not undefined. But I did try after removing **dataSet1 &&** but the problem still persists. I will try a couple of other ways. Thank you for your suggestions @phn, appreciated!!!